# Python 3.5.2 Installation of Cherrypy with apt

Tags: python, ubuntu, cherrypy

i developed a small web APP with CherryPy for Python. I want to run this on a production Server with ubuntu 16.04. My Sysadmin tells me that I shall not use pip or github repository, because of ... something wrong with using anything but apt ... he says.

Is there a way of getting a recent cherrypy for python3 with apt ?

Comment: Answered at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cherrypy-users/WABmCe73luk/RAhHbr5dAgAJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution on Ubuntu 16.04 with python3 (Python 3.5.2):

## Install virtualenvironment for python3

sudo apt-get install python3-venv

## Create a folder for your environment

mkdir environment

## Create the environment

python3 -m venv environment

## Change into folder

cd environment/bin

## Activate environment

source activate

## Install pip within the env

apt install python3-pip

## Install cherrypy >= 18.1.0

pip3 install cherrypy

## Run program

python3 ./my_python_script.py

Answer (score 0):

Its absolutly fine instaling cherrypy on Ubuntu. 
Here what I have done on my server:

**First Install `pip`**

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

OR

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

OR for Python3 (try apt or apt-get)

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

**After installing `pip`**, Install `cherrypy`

```
pip install cherrypy
```

Make sure you have installed python and based on the python version install pip. After installing pip, everything will be fine. This works for me on my Ubuntu servers.

Comment: then use easy_install which is the part of setuptools. make sure first setuptools and then use easy_install command to install cherrypy. i can post detail if you want but first try using easy_install